# How to make a console application created with Visual C++ run without mfc140u.dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a console application created with Visual C++ (VS 2015), which builds an .exe executable file. It runs fine on my PC. However, when put on a PC that does not have VS installed, it throws this error:

> The program can't start because mfc140u.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

If I put the mfc140u.dll on that PC, next to the .exe file, then the executable works fine. However, I would like to avoid distributing this mfc140u.dll file if at all possible. I have not been able to figure out how to do so. My solution doesn't reference anything that remotely resembles "mfc140u".

Update: I just learned that mfc140.dll is the MFC library introduced by VS 2015+. However, I'm still unsure what this mfc140u.dll (note the extra 'u' at the end) is about.

Comment: Getting a dependency on MFC in a console mode app is, cough, unusual.  First make sure you don't link it.  Then make sure that you know where your libraries came from.  Then use the linker's /VERBOSE option so you can double-check any assumptions.

Comment: Just statically link to MFC and you no longer need any DLL to run your program (apart from standard system DLLs ofc). You'll find this setting on the first page of your project configuration.

Comment: Strange close vote, this is by far not an opinion-based question.

Comment: @zett42 , why don’t you make that an aswer? i think this is correct.

Comment: @Aganju I'm sure this question is a duplicate but I didn't have time to search for a good one yet.

Comment: @zett42 You won't find the duplicate question. My reputation is only 467 but my google-fu is pretty good, trust me :)

Comment: The `u` is typically a Unicode version (vs. wide character).

Comment: @crashmstr is there some kind of encoding setting in a VC++ project that I can change to get rid of this dependency?

Comment: @Zoomzoom don't use MFC? You still might need other C or C++ libraries either way.